# How to make a regex for /vi/<number>.htm(l)?

Tags: python, regex

My pattern that already matches e.g. `/vi/9822` is `/vi/([^/]+)?` 
I also want to match e.g. `/vi/9822.htm` and `/vi/9822.html`. Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the .htm or .html part is optional, this should suit your needs: `/vi/(\d+)(\.html?)?`, otherwise use just `/vi/(\d+)\.html?`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\.html?` to the end of what you already have, optionally removing or moving the existing `?`.